# Pandas - Set value based on idxmax of group, including NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set the value of a column, "C" based on the idxmax() of a groupby ("B").  To make it a bit more complicated though, in the event of a NaN or 0, I would like it to return the min value excluding the NaN or 0 if such a value exists.  Here is an example dataframe:

| Index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | False |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | False |
| 2 | 2 | 9 | False |
| 3 | 2 | NaN | False |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | False |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | False |
| 6 | 4 | NaN | False |
| 7 | 4 | NaN | False |
| 8 | 5 | 0 | False |
| 9 | 5 | 5 | False |

I am trying to set column "C" to True for the idxmax() of column B, split by a groupby on column "A":

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | True |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | False |
| 2 | 2 | 9 | True |
| 3 | 2 | NaN | False |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | True |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | False |
| 6 | 4 | NaN | True |
| 7 | 4 | NaN | False |
| 8 | 5 | 0 | False |
| 9 | 5 | 5 | True |

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work? `df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('idxmin') == df.index`

Comment: Honestly I'm still trying to figure out how to use transform.

Comment: The way I think about transform is that it returns a value for each row on your dataframe.  That value is calculate by the group.

Comment: Could I use transform to set the value of another column though?  Like I might with a .loc[] ?

Comment: Yes, `df['C_new'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('idxmax') == df.index` and because of the magic of pandas intrinsic data alignment it will match the rows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use groupby with transform like this:

```
df['C_new'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('idxmax') == df.index
```

Output:

```
   Index  A     B      C  C_new
0      0  1   5.0  False  False
1      1  1  10.0  False   True
2      2  2   9.0  False   True
3      3  2   NaN  False  False
4      4  3   3.0  False  False
5      5  3   5.0  False   True
```

or, idxmin...

```
df['C_new'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('idxmin') == df.index
```

Output:

```
   Index  A     B      C  C_new
0      0  1   5.0  False   True
1      1  1  10.0  False  False
2      2  2   9.0  False   True
3      3  2   NaN  False  False
4      4  3   3.0  False   True
5      5  3   5.0  False  False
```

Comment: I'm just testing this now.  There might be some special cases where this doesnt work.  I'm going to update the question for a more complete dataset.  --Edited the question.

Comment: Please do... you might have some edge case that need to be accounted for.

Comment: I can think of two problems.... All NaN in a group and multiple maxes/mines only the first one is getting marked in a group.

Comment: Yup agree - any thoughts on how to deal with those.   The "All NaN" I think can be dealt with fillna(0) on the series, as I am treating them similarly in this case.

Comment: If you wanted to be really safe about negative numbers you can fill with -np.inf