# pandas DataFrame, loc, groupby, idxmax and NA values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let suppose I have this Data Frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        1: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        2: ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', pd.NA, 'x'],
        3: [10, 8, 8, 10, 7, pd.NA, 0],
        4: [4, 4, 5, 7, 8, pd.NA, 0]
    },
)
```

```
   1     2     3     4
0  a     x    10     4
1  a     y     8     4
2  a     y     8     5
3  b     x    10     7
4  b     y     7     8
5  c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  d     x     0     0
```

For the group of the same value in column 1, the group of the the same value in column 2, I want to keep only the rows for which the value in column 3 is the max (first max encountered in case of equalities).
Importantly, I also want to keep the rows with NA values.

Below is the expected result (note the index values):

```
   1     2     3     4
0  a     x    10     4
1  a     y     8     4
3  b     x    10     7
4  b     y     7     8
5  c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  d     x     0     0
```

First, because of NA values, I have to tell to pandas the types of the columns:

```py
df[3] = pandas.to_numeric(df[3])
```

Grouping by columns 1 and 2 is done thanks to the method `groupby`, and keeping the NA values during the grouping is done by the keyword parameters `dropna=False`:

```py
df.groupby([1, 2], dropna=False)
```

The `groupby` method must be followed by a transformation function.
Here we want to have the first occurrence of the max in each group.
I first tried to do this with `loc`:

```py
df2: pd.DataFrame = df.loc[
    df.groupby([1, 2], dropna=False)[3].idxmax()
]
```

This throw an exception:

```py
KeyError: '[nan] not in index'
```

I want to keep column 4 (and a DataFrame object).
Else, I should do this:

```py
df2: pd.DataFrame = df.groupby([1,2], dropna=False)[3].max()
```

What's wrong?

Is this related to [pandas issue 52234](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52234)?

#### Versions

- **Python** 3.9
- **pandas** 2.0.1

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is for sure a more *robust solution* but you can still try this one :

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/72957882/16120011
df2 = df.loc[df.fillna(0).groupby([1, 2])[3].transform("idxmax").eq(df.index)]
```

​
Output :

```
print(df2)

   1     2     3     4
0  a     x    10     4
1  a     y     8     4
3  b     x    10     7
4  b     y     7     8
5  c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  d     x     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you, this work for me.
As I answered to @God-is-one, I would prefer a solution that does not change the NaN to values that can impact the calculus (e.g. the mean).
I will mark this as accepted answer instead.